# How to call the python function from the javascript ajax request result?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax

So I have the function I want to call `get_maps()` from a separate python file called "mapsinterpeter.py", and I have successfully requested the code, but I still cannot call the function.

```
function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if(year.value === "" || cat.value === "") {
        msg.textContent = "Please fill out the fields"
        msg.classList.add("error");
    } else {
        msg.textContent = ""
        msg.classList.remove("error");
        const catvalue = cat.value
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "mapsinterpeter.py",
            data: {async: false},
            success: function (response) {
           console.log(get_maps(/*args, ect */));
       },
        });
        year.value = ""
        cat.value = ""
    } 
}
```

Console:

```
get_maps is not defined
at Object.success (https://6534e288-58df-4278-82e3-7bfc760af484.id.repl.co/script.js:34:20)
at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js:2:28327)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js:2:29072)
at l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js:2:79901)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js:2:82355)
```

Comment: what do you mean you have successfully requested the code? have you imported the other file so you can call the function in that file?

Comment: @tygzy ? the other file just defines ```get_maps()```, meanwhile the request I sent only returned me the python code for that function. So imagine the other file has ```def get_maps() #code```, the request would only retrieve the code and not what the function returns

Answer (score 0):

You can't call it directly from the javascript file

You have to call it and pass params from the AJAX call and then call the .done method when the API executes and do something with the values

```js
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "~/mapsinterpeter.py", // Change the path to match this
      data: { param: text} // params for function
    }).done(function( e ) {
       // do something with function response
       
    });
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but while using this method I first of all get an error on the file path, then second I just get the python code, and I'm unable to get the function's response